# Remove BSON Object ID when querying mongo DB using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I'm using Pymongo and flask to build a rest API, and the documents are stored in the following BSON format:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('123'), 'title':"test"}
```

how can I query the Mongo DB to get the document in the following format or convert the query result to the following format?

```
{'_id':'123', 'title':"test"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return .str of ObjectID using pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159627/return-str-of-objectid-using-pymongo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `str` to your `ObjectId`:

```py
item = {'_id': ObjectId('123'), 'title':"test"}
item['_id'] = str(item['_id'])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes I ended up doing this, was wondering if there any better way to achieve this using BSON API?

Comment: You can change the type used by the document through the `MongoClient` constructor `document_class` parameter (defaults to `dict`), but I am not aware of any way to change the serialization of a specific field.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you wish to rename the _id of the document in the collection. You can do this by querying the database collection then replacing the document in the collection.

```
myquery = {'title':"test"}
# _ = col.find(myquery)
# To check if it exists
y = db['my collection'].update_one(myquery, {"$set": {'_id': '123'}})
```

Hope it helps. If you give me more info about database and collection I could help more.

Comment: Hi Bryce, thanks for the reply.
No, I don't want to update the database, I need to convert the document to a proper JSON format when sending the result via rest API 
`{'_id':'123', 'title':"test"}`

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, this will replace your ObjectID('123') to '123'

Comment: Yes, I don't want to make changes to Database.
I want to keep the data in BSON format in the mongo but want to convert that to above-expected format when sending to the client.